# How to have git-svn take care of empty directories gracefully?

Tags: git, directory, git-svn

I am very happily using git-svn, though I noticed that git has a different approach when it comes to empty directories as SVN. I need a way to get around the following particular situation:

I have in my project's SVN repository several empty directories that belong in there and should not be touched. Due to some refactoring, I had to delete another directory that used to have files in it. `git svn dcommit` deletes the files, but leaves the directory. It strikes me that git's ignorance of empty directories is resulting in inconsistency in my SVN repo.

I would like to have that particular directory removed from my SVN repository. Can git-svn do that? And if not, how should I be doing that? (And - eventually - how can I do that while committing other files with them as well in the same changeset?)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use rmdir argument or config parameter:

> --rmdir
>
> Only used with the dcommit, set-tree and commit-diff commands.
>
> Remove directories from the SVN tree if there are no files left
>   behind. SVN can version empty directories, and they are not removed by
>   default if there are no files left in them. git cannot version empty 
>   directories. Enabling this flag will make the commit to SVN act like 
>   git.
>
> config key: svn.rmdir

Comment: _Enabling this flag will make the commit to SVN act like git._ Which is exactly not what I want; I want SVN to be distinctive about whether or not empty directories are in the tree. I just want to remove one empty directory (of many existing) in particular on the SVN side, not all of them.

Comment: If you switch on the parameter, it would not delete existing empty directories. But next time you delete last file from a directory, `dcommit` will delete the directory from svn too, in one commit. If you want change something with empty directories in svn which was committed already, you should use SVN directly, the `rmdir` affects only `dcommit`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I tested it with a local repo, and it does exactly what you describe. For some reason I didn't learn that from the manual you quoted. (I read the first sentence as "All empty dirs will be removed"). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can this be configured as the default when using git-svn?

Comment: @SamHendley "config key: svn.rmdir" - so, just `git config --global svn.rmdir true`.

Answer (score 13):

You will have to delete it on the SVN side:

```
svn delete -m "deleting empty dir" http://path/to/deleted/dir
```

Comment: +1, though I am not very happy with that for two reasons: 1. I need to type the repo path specifically every time I want to do something like this, and 2. It takes a separate commit to get it done. Is this the only option there is?